# Where are my Magento Backups?

Tags: magento-1.9, backup

I am performing regular backups of my store, however, when I navigate to `/var/backups/`, I don't see the backup files.  I only see the old backups from a month ago (and earlier) in the backups directory.

When I perform a backup, the backup shows in the admin (`System > Tools > Backups`).  I do not see the older backups that I see in the /var/backups folder.

Did Magento change the location of the storage for these physical backups (perhaps with a new security patch)?  Where can I see what the path is?  I want to copy it to my network as a plan B.

I am using Magento 1.9.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the folder has always been `var/backups`.
See the method `Mage_Backup_Helper_Data::getBackupsDir()`

```
public function getBackupsDir()
{
    return Mage::getBaseDir('var') . DS . 'backups';
}
```

it's there in 1.9 and it has been there since the backup module was introduced.

Make sure the folder is writeable and you have enough disk space.

**[EDIT]**
I was half right in my original answer.
I assumed that `Mage::getBaseDir('var')` always returns `MAGENTO_ROOT/var` but that's not always true.
Take a look at the method: `Mage_Core_Model_Config_Options::getVarDir()` (this is called when determining the var dir).

```
public function getVarDir()
{
    //$dir = $this->getDataSetDefault('var_dir', $this->getBaseDir().DS.'var');
    $dir = isset($this->_data['var_dir']) ? $this->_data['var_dir']
        : $this->_data['base_dir'] . DS . self::VAR_DIRECTORY;
    if (!$this->createDirIfNotExists($dir)) {
        $dir = $this->getSysTmpDir().DS.'magento'.DS.'var';
        if (!$this->createDirIfNotExists($dir)) {
            throw new Mage_Core_Exception('Unable to find writable var_dir');
        }
    }
    return $dir;
}
```

If the var folder cannot be created magento uses as var dir the system tmp folder and creates `magento/var` inside it.
So for linux that should be `/tmp/magento/var`.
Take a look in there, maybe you will find your missing backups.

Comment: I didn't get a writable error from the admin when performing the backup which I usually get if there's a permission problem.

Comment: Also, plenty of disk space.

Comment: Could be a permission issue after all.  I viewed the permissions of the folder and it said that Apache is the owner so I am going to have IT fix that form me so I can make sure that the permissions are writable.  Weird that there wasn't an error message about that and it takes the normal amount of time to build a backup.  Also strange that the backups appear in the admin.  Thanks!

Comment: @NotJay. Your comment made me dig deeper. See my updated answer. This should clear the fog for "the backups appear in the admin" (I hope).

Comment: /var/tmp/ is empty.

Comment: Do you know linux commands?  What would I need to type in the terminal to find that type of file?

Comment: I figured out the command... `find /var/www/html/magento/ -name "*.tgz"` however, it only found the old copies.

Comment: Changing the permissions solved this dilemma.  Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 4):

It may be that Magento doesn't have write permissions to your `var/` directory and uses system temp directory instead.

Look on `Mage_Core_Model_Config_Options::getVarDir()` method implementation. If Magento uses system tmp directory as fallback, your backups can be created in `/tmp/magento/var/backups/` directory.

Comment: Ha. Just realized this now myself. :)

Comment: Yeah, this is first place to look in such case :-)

Comment: tmp is empty :-/

Comment: Maybe try to dump `Mage::getBaseDir('var') . DS . 'backups'` somewhere to check which path it uses.

Comment: System temp is the one you find in the root directory => `/` and therefore `/tmp`. Welcome to the *nix filesystem where duplication is done on per user, per process, etc. Many var's and tmp's, depends on context.

Comment: @FiascoLabs I looked at all the tmp folders.  I did notice that once I saw `/magemto/` in the path from both answers.  Thanks!